# Windows 7 hibernate only locks computer

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I use hibernate every day. Recently (without any conscious change from me) it stopped working. Whenever the computer is supposed to hibernate, it only locks the computer. Clicking hibernate, pressing the power button and (worst) low battery all have the same effect.

I don't even know how to trouble shoot this situation. Sleep works. hiberfil.sys exists. Hibernation is in the list of choices for the power button.

This happens always, even directly after a reboot.

edit: since i dont know how to format in comments:

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /enum all
The boot configuration data store could not be opened. 
The configuration registry database is corrupt.
```

edit: i was told to try `bootrec /rebuildbcd`. this doesnt exist in regular or safe mode, but according to google in repair mode. so i booted into that mode, it detected on its own that there's a problem and asked, if i wanted to fix it. i clicked yes, and now hibernate works again.

edit: apparently, my question is kind of a duplicate of:
[How to diagnose failure to hibernate after hard drive swap (yet sleep works fine)?](https://superuser.com/questions/98380/how-to-diagnose-failure-to-hibernate-after-hard-drive-swap-yet-sleep-works-fine?rq=1)

Comment: Check resumeobject and hibernation record in BCD: `bcdedit /enum all`

Comment: interesting, apparently "The configuration registry database is corrupt." what does that mean and how do i "uncorrupt" it?

Comment: Reboot to safe mode and use `bootrec /rebuildbcd`, that'll recreate BCD database. Recommend you to backup original /Boot/BCD file first, also I would prepare at least install DVD or USB or some recovery PE in case something goes wrong.

Comment: safe mode doesnt know bootrec, apparently repair mode does. but repair mode detected on its own that something is wrong, and fixed it. problem solved. now you can create an answer for me to accept. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow BCD database got corrupt.

Solution is to reboot to `Repair mode` and either run Automatic repair or use command prompt and repair BCD with `bootrec /rebuildbcd`.

In this case, Repair mode detected corrupt database and rebuild it automatically.

It's good practice to backup original /Boot/BCD file first. Also it's good to have at least install DVD or USB or some recovery PE in case something goes wrong.

In case you have multiboot setup, this procedure might mess it up.